# Подскажите, как убрать излишки слова в массиве

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

Подскажите пожалуйста. У меня есть матрица nxm в которую я записываю предложение (строки=слова, столбцы=буквы). Есть такое условие, чтобы слово не было больше 20 букв. Когда я, например, ввожу слово больше 20 букв, то остаток слова переходит на вторую строчку=>во второе слово(а оно мне не надо, нужно, чтобы этот остаток просто удалился). Как можно это реализовать???

Comment: Не вводить в матрицу больше 20 символов :) - например, пишите их по одному...

Answer (score 0):

А ты создай однострочный массив специально для ввода - все что записываешь, записывается в него, а потом просто перебрасываешь символы из этого массива в основной пока не достигнут 20-й символ или не достигнут `\0`.